# How to use a user as a ForeignKey in a Django model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've got this model in my Django application:

```py
class ClubSession(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coach = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I can run `python manage.py makemigrations club_sessions` without issue but when I thn run `python manage.py migrate club_sessions` I get `ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'username'`. `username` is a superuser and already exists.

How do I resolve this?

This is the latest migration:

```py
# Generated by Django 3.0.6 on 2020-05-28 15:07

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('club_sessions', '0004_auto_20200528_1450'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='clubsession',
            name='coach',
            field=models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ),
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='clubsession',
            name='location',
            field=models.CharField(max_length=200),
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: do you have a user with id of value 'username'?

Comment: Can you please show the related migration?

Comment: I added the migration to the question.

Comment: @runnerpaul: it looks like you already had a field `coach` or something, and that you changed the type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Django lets a `ForeignKey` refer to the *primary key* of the target model. This also has some advantages to make relations more uniform.

If you really want to save the `username` in the `ForeignKey`, you can specify a [**`to_field=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field) and let it refer to a column that is unique (the `username` of the default `User` model is unique), so we can refer to it with:

```
from django.conf import settings

class ClubSession(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field='username'
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    details = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

You will need to remove the already existing migration and make a new one in order to migrate the database properly.

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).